Display text as code in IDE tooltip when describing my components
I m trying to create doc for my components while using them. Basically, I'm adding comments over all my functions headers like this :
/**
 * this is some text
 * @param text this is some text
 * @returns this is some text
 */
export default function component(props: any) {

I want to describe the tooltip when hovering my functions inside VScode.
I'd like to have something like the example in this image. Here, the code example is well formatted and easier to read.
example in vscode

This sounds like a question as to what type of doc-strings VS Code recognises when formatting tool-tips. Please add visual-studio-code as a tag. Using capitals for words like "I" and "VS" makes those names for recognisable.

Solution is to surround your code example inside < ` >. Exemple :
/**
 * this is some text
 * `This will be in a code format`
 */
export default function component(props: any) {

